# Problem with Magento 1.4.1.1 Mage.php

Tags: error, magento-community, ce-1.4.1.1

I am attempting to get the quantity of an item by inputting the sku. The following code works great on my WAMP local installation:

```
require_once('app\Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();
$sku='TEST1';
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product/info')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);
$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product); 
echo $stock->getQty();
```

However, when I change to the production server I get the following errors:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: apc.shm_size now uses M/G suffixes, please update your ini files in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Cache_Exception' with message 'can't get apc memory size' in /var/www/html/Example.com/us/lib/Zend/Cache.php:208
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/Example.com/us/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/Apc.php(191): Zend_Cache::throwException('can't get apc m...')
#1 /var/www/html/Example.com/us/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/TwoLevels.php(488): Zend_Cache_Backend_Apc->getFillingPercentage()
#2 /var/www/html/Example.com/us/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/TwoLevels.php(173): Zend_Cache_Backend_TwoLevels->_getFastFillingPercentage('saving')
#3 /var/www/html/Example.com/us/lib/Zend/Cache/Core.php(381): Zend_Cache_Backend_TwoLevels->save('a:7:{s:10:"bloc...', 'JFMG_CORE_CACHE...', Array, NULL)
#4 /var/www/html/Example.com/us/lib/Varien/Cache/Core.php(76): Zend_Cache_Core->save('a:7:{s:10:"bloc...', 'CORE_CACHE_OPTI...', Array, NULL, 8)
#5 /var/www/html/Example.com/us/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(349): Varien_Cache_Core->save('a:7:{s:10:"bloc...', 'CORE_CACHE_OPTI...', Array, NULL)
#6 /var/www/html/Example.com/us/app/code/c in /var/www/html/Example.com/us/lib/Zend/Cache.php on line 208
```

The production server is running Linux so I did change the back slash to forward slash in the first line to:

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
```

"Example.com" is substituted for my domain name. In both cases I am using Magento 1.4.1.1. Any help or comments would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is stated right here:

```
PHP Startup: apc.shm_size now uses M/G suffixes, please update your ini files in Unknown on line 0
```

Find your apc.ini (or it may be located in your php.ini), and fix the apc.shm_size.

Comment: Yep, pretty much it.

Comment: I corrected the apc.ini file and the error message regarding that is gone. I am still left with the PHP Fatal error though. I did restart the server after changing the apc.ini. Any ideas on what to try next? Thanks.

Comment: It turns out that I can run the php code from the web browser but not from the command line. I've read that I need to add apc.enable_cli = 1 to the apc.ini file to be able to run the code from the command line. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find out if there are any security or performance implications from adding that. Does anyone know what that will change?